# Accesing constructor's base class properties

Tags: c#, radix, componentone

In order to use a C1DropDownControl inside a C1InputPanel I need to define a class that inherits from the InputControlHost class and then invoke the desired control's constructor, like this:

```
public class InputC1DropDownControl : InputControlHost
{
    public InputC1DropDownControl()
        : base(new C1DropDownControl())
    {

    }
}
```

By doing that I can see the C1DropDownControl inside the C1InputPanel (it's some kind of a special ComboBox) but I can't access all of it's properties. So, my question is: how can I access the C1DropDownControl properties from an InputC1DropDownControl object (which obviously inherits from a different class)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the `Control` property and then cast:

```
var control = (C1DropDownControl) controlHost.Control;
// Use the various properties
```

Answer (score 0):

The `InputControlHost` has a property called `Control`. You should be able to do something like

```
C1DropDownControl hostedControl = Control as C1DropDownControl;
hostedControl.Whatever...
```

in your InputC1DropDownControl class.